# Best practice for including a Spring project dependency

Tags: spring

If I have a maven based spring project and there are multiple modules/projects. What is the right way to add the dependency of one module to another.

Say, I have two modules M1 and M2 (they have **xml based spring configuration**).
Now, if I have to add dependency of M2 into M1, I add M2 as a dependency in M1's pom.xml.

**Am I also supposed to import the applicationConfig of M2 in M1's applicationConfig xml ?**

I am more concerned about the best practice here.

I am aware that if M1 is not using any of the bean's defined in M2's applicationConfig, even if the import is not used, it works fine. But is there any best practice around importing of spring modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question is:

**Am I also supposed to import the applicationConfig of M2 in M1's applicationConfig xml ? - (As you have answered.)**

- Yes - (If M2 dependencies are injected into M1 code.)
- No  - (If M2
  dependencies are not injected into M1. It is something like adding
  any other dependency to your project)

You can import any number of XML spring configuration files into another spring xml file.. but you can follow the best practice of component-scan that your are mentioning in the xml files. Keep it to the lowest possible level of packaging structure.

Best practices based on my experience:

- Always add import statements at the top of the xml files. (More
  readable.. again a personal flavour. But just be consistent all
  across your project.)